# Is it possible to pass the goBack() function as a parameter

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a function AccountScreen. From this screen I would like to be able to `navigate.goBack()`. I tried following the guide [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/) on how to go back to a previous screen but I am getting an error.

Here is my code:

AccountScreen.js

```
const BackButton = styled.Button`

`;


function AccountScreen({doThis}) {
    return(
        <Root>
            <BackButton title="" onPress={() => doThis} />
            <Text>Account</Text>
        </Root>
    )
};

export default AccountScreen;
```

navigations.js

```
const createProfileDrawer = ({navigation}) => 
            <Drawer.Navigator>
                <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen}/>
                <Drawer.Screen name="Account" 
                component={AccountScreen(navigation.goBack())} />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
```

So when I try and pass it like this I get an error `The action 'GO_BACK' was not handled by any navigator.` Is it possible to pass a function like this?

Comment: Why are you passing as a parameter when you can access it directly.

Comment: When I try to access it directly I get ```Can't find variable: navigation```

Comment: there is other methods of accessing route without navigation prop, have you tried? or you can use hoc (withNavigation) for getting this prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the following changes:

in `AccountScreen.js`:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function AccountScreen() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    return(
        <Root>
            <BackButton title="" onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} />
```

in `navigations.js`:

```
<Drawer.Screen name="Account" component={AccountScreen} />
```

Note that action you want is likely not 'goBack' but 'openDrawer'.